# choppy movement in ie 11 when scroll x

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll

```
var leftOffset = parseInt($("#header").css('left'));
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset
    });
});
```

i use the above function to make a div fixed on scroll horizontal but the refreshes are kind of choppy when you do smooth scrolling (eg: by dragging the scrollbar). It seems javascript refresh is slower than css refresh. Any solution for this?

if you try this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/EzXub/263/

code on ie 11 , you can see the flickering effect when scrolling x

Comment: it is working perfect in chrome but not in internet explorer 11 the content flickered everytime i scroll horizontally

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the browser itself and the resources which are allocated. Try it from a different machine and see if the behavior is same.

Comment: hi , it happens the same thing..:(